# Avoiding exhausting GPU resources in convNN Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, gpu, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to run a hyperparameter optimization  script, for a convNN using Tensorflow. 
As you may know, TF handling of the GPU-Memory isn't that fancy(don't think it will ever be, thanks to the TPU). So my question is how do I know to choose the filter dimensions and the batchsize, so that the GPU-memory don't get exhausted. 
Here's the equation that I'm thinking of:

```
image_shape =128x128x3(3 color channel) 
batchSitze  = 20 ( is the smallest possible batchsize, since I got 20 klasses) 
filter_shape= fw_fh_fd[filter_width=4, filter_height=4, filter_depth=32]
```

As far as understood, using `tf.conv2d` function will need the following amount of memory:

```
image_width * image_height *numerofchannel*batchSize*filter_height*filter_width*filter_depth*32bit
```

since we're `tf.float32` type  for each pixel. 
in the given example, the needed memory, will be :
`128x128x3x20x4x4x32x32 =16106127360  (bits)`, which is all most 16GB of memory.

I'm not the formula is correct, so I hope to get a validation or the a correction of what I'm missing.

Comment: Andrew Karpathy's blog http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ explains how to calculate memory required by a conv net. Scroll down to the last part of the blog. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this will take only about 44MB of memory, mostly taken by the output.

- Your input is `20x128x128x3`
- The convolution kernel is `4x4x3x32`
- The output is `20x128x128x32`

When you sum up the total, you get

```
(20*128*128*3 + 4*4*3*32 + 20*128*128*32) * 4 / 1024**2 ≈ 44MB
```

(In the above, `4` is for the size in bytes of `float32` and `1024**2` is to get the result in MB).

Your batch size can be smaller than your number of classes. Think about ImageNet and its 1000 classes: people are training with batch sizes 10 times smaller.

**EDIT**

Here is a tensorboard screenshot of the net — it reports 40MB rather than 44MB, probably because it excludes the input — and you also have all the tensor sizes I mentioned earlier.

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying, but would u please explain how  u got the 44MB ?

Comment: Summing it all up: `(20*128*128*3+4*4*3*32+20*128*128*32)*4/1024**2=43.75`

Comment: But you're multiplying the filter values with the input and where  do got the *4/1024**2 ?

Comment: I understand your answer now, but I still don't agree with the addition, since the conv operation as whole is saved in gpu RAM, I need to test this, I'll do it tomorrow. thanks a lot for your help